# Estimate number of songs a radio station has

Tags: probability, statistics, estimation, experimental-mathematics

Imagine the following problem:

You listen to a radio station and take notes how often was each song played. How can you estimate based on your notes (e.g. 30 songs played once, 2 played twice, one song three times) how many songs has the radio station available when we assume all the songs are played with a uniform distribution?

Comment: You mean : The probability of each song being played is equal.

Comment: Yeah, discrete uniform distribution.

Answer (score 1):

You could determine the probability that the observed frequency of songs occurs for each number $N$ of songs and maximize it.